# counting database hits by user type in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, logfile

I have a reverse access log file that I've processed to just be the url hit and user type. I need to count the number of times a given url is hit by each of the user types. 
sample data:

> http://find.galegroup.com:80/ staff
>      http://www.transnational-dispute-management.com:80/ student
>      https://www.investorstatelawguide.com:443/ AdjunctVisiting
>      https://www.jstor.org:443/ faculty
>      https://bmo.bmiresearch.com:443/ mainlibrary
>      https://heinonline.org:443/ oncampus
>      http://find.galegroup.com:80/ student

I was thinking to put each url as a tuple with counters for each user type. As each line is read it is tested against previous matches - if it doesn't have any matches then a new tuple is initiated. If it does have a match, the appropriate counter is incremented and the tuple resaved.

At the end all the tuples are written out to a new file.

Problem is I haven't a clue how to implement it.

Pointers, general strategies, and answers greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'd be far better off reformatting the data into a standard format like CSV and then loading it into memory with a library like numpy or pandas; then counting on it becomes just a matter of basic usage of Python libraries. Or look into structured logging techniques.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do this task with regular expression, we can simply define a simple expression using alternation such as:

```
(galegroup\.com)|(jstor\.org)|(investorstatelawguide\.com)
```

capture our desired domains, then we would just count:

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wYMSev/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(galegroup\.com)|(jstor\.org)|(investorstatelawguide\.com)"

test_str = ("http://find.galegroup.com:80/ staff http://www.transnational-dispute-management.com:80/ student https://www.investorstatelawguide.com:443/ AdjunctVisiting https://www.jstor.org:443/ faculty https://bmo.bmiresearch.com:443/ mainlibrary https://heinonline.org:443/ oncampus http://find.galegroup.com:80/ student\n"
    "http://find.galegroup.com:80/ staff http://www.transnational-dispute-management.com:80/ student https://www.investorstatelawguide.com:443/ AdjunctVisiting https://www.jstor.org:443/ faculty https://bmo.bmiresearch.com:443/ mainlibrary https://heinonline.org:443/ oncampus http://find.galegroup.com:80/ student\n"
    "http://find.galegroup.com:80/ staff http://www.transnational-dispute-management.com:80/ student https://www.investorstatelawguide.com:443/ AdjunctVisiting https://www.jstor.org:443/ faculty https://bmo.bmiresearch.com:443/ mainlibrary https://heinonline.org:443/ oncampus http://find.galegroup.com:80/ student")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Expected results: I only partially understand your answer, but I don't think it gets me all the way there.The file has hundreds of unique urls that are hit by different user types hundreds of times. In the end I want a file with a list of each database (only listed once) followed by the number of staff hits, student hits, faculty hits... then on to the next url, its user type counts, etc. In your example I get each database multiple times and no counts of user types. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.I'm pretty new to this.